# C# Moving a cross into a picturebox based on the Thumbstick Position

Tags: c#, draw, picturebox, move

I want to draw a cross into a picturebox. In the next step I want to move the cross based on my Data.
Which is the Thumbsticks position. I want it to appear similar to the figure below. 
[image]

Here is my Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SlimDX;
using SlimDX.XInput;

namespace Controller_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        GamepadState Controller = new GamepadState(UserIndex.One);
        Graphics drawArea;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            drawArea = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        }    

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Controller.Update();
            var LeftStick = Controller.LeftStick;
            float LeftStickX = LeftStick.Position.X;
            float LeftStickY = LeftStick.Position.Y;

            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black);

            //  horizontal Line 
            drawArea.DrawLine(blackPen, x1+LeftStickX, y1-LeftStickY,   x2+LeftStickX, y2-LeftStickY);
        // vertical Line
            drawArea.DrawLine(blackPen, x1+LeftStickX, y1-LeftStickY, x2+LeftStickX, y2-LeftStickY);
        }
    }
    public class GamepadState
    {Get Postiton......}
}
```

My problem now is, if I move the Thumbstick every time a new cross is drawn but the old one is still in the 
Picturebox like in the figure below. If i use the pictureBox1.Invalidate():/pictureBox1.Refresh(); Funtcion
the cross becomes invisible and is not displayed anymore. The interval of the timer is on 1. 
[image]

What could i change in order to get the code to work?

Comment: Assuming you __really want to draw in this volitile and non-persistent__ way: simply add a `pictureBox1.Refresh() or a  drawArea.Clear(Color.Transparent)` __before__ drawing new stuff. - And: As __I believe I have told you before__, a Timer.Interval should never be less than 15-25! You need to poll using XInput , but not more often that neccesary!

Comment: So I am new in C#!! If there is any better way to do this, I´m open for Ideas.
If you read my Text correctly, you would have noticed that  I already used pictureBox1.Refresh() and consequently the cross became invisible, which was in no way what I intended !
You didn´t tell me  about any timer before my friend ! 
I prefer answers in a more polite way.

Comment: If you read my comment again you may see that I have __bolded__ the word 'before'. You didn't tell us where you put the Refresh but I told you where it should go.  You seem to have deleted the previous version of the question with the very same screenshot where I told you that Timers have a resolution of less than 15ms. So setting Intervall to less than that doesn't help matters.

Comment: Also: Best not to 'cache' the Graphics object! For persistent results always use the Paint's  e.Graphics and for drawing volatile results (like a rubber-band rectangle) create it freshly when you need it!